# Vuetify Dropdown List not working properly

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

I add a dropdown list to my project using the Vuetify example and this happens

The list is at the bottom of my page, I'm guessing is the CSS but is kinda confusing try to figure out which part.

Code

```
<v-container>
  <v-layout wrap align-center id="new">
          <v-flex xs12 sm6 d-flex>
            <v-select :items="items"
                      label="Standard"></v-select>
          </v-flex>
  </v-layout>
</v-container>
```

Script

```
data: () => ({
  items: ['Foo', 'Bar', 'Fizz', 'Buzz'],
}),
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to wrap you're app in the `v-app` tag for things to operate properly when using Vuetify. In this case wrap the `v-container` with `v-app` tag and your select will display properly. More about `v-app` [here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/layout/pre-defined#all-about-app).

```
<v-app>
  <v-navigation-drawer app></v-navigation-drawer>
  <v-toolbar app></v-toolbar>
  <v-content>
    <v-container fluid>
      <router-view></router-view>
    </v-container>
  </v-content>
  <v-footer app></v-footer>
</v-app>
```

Comment: `v-content` too. Especially is there are any toolbars or navigation drawers with the `app` property. Your answer already has `v-content` but mentioning why might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Similar artifacts can be caused by relative position parents, i figured out part of the fix, just don't know how to integrate it yet.

This is the github bug report for that issue
https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/9933